# Is there a way to overplot a line onto a 2D color plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 2D color plot that looks like this:

[image]

and I want to add a horizontal line running across it, indicating a particular time delay value. Is there a way to do this using matplotlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean an [`axhspan`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhspan)?

This will draw an horizontal line at the height or the special value from the left border to the right border of your ax. The y-values are in the data coordinates while the x-values are in Axes coordinates.

```
ax.axhspan(special_value, special_value, xmin=0, xmax=1, color="red")
```

You can specify a big upper/lower boundary so that the whole area above/below that special value is colored too, or you can use an [`axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline) as suggested by *@import random* if you want a single line.

Comment: Might be simpler with [axhline](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed @importrandom, thank you!